# Pandas create new dataframe by querying other dataframes without using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two huge dataframes that both have the same id field. I want to make a simple summary dataframe where I show the maximum of specific columns. I understand `iterrows()` is frowned upon, so are a couple one-liners to do this? I don't understand lambda/apply very well, but maybe this would work here.

**Stand-alone example**

```
import pandas as pd

myid = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
name =['A','A','B','C','D','D','E']
x = [15,12,3,3,1,4,8]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(myid, name, x)), 
                  columns=['myid', 'name', 'x'])
display(df1)

myid = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5]
name =['A','B','B','B','C','D','E','E']
y = [9,6,3,4,6,2,8,2]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(myid, name, y)), 
                  columns=['myid', 'name', 'y'])
display(df2)

mylist = df['myid'].unique()
df_summary = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['MY_ID'])
## do work here...
```

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `merge()`
- named aggregations

```
df1.merge(df2, on=["myid","name"], how="outer")\
.groupby(["myid","name"], as_index=False).agg(MAX_X=("x","max"),MAX_Y=("y","max"))
```

|  | myid | name | MAX_X | MAX_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | 15 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | B | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | C | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | D | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | E | 8 | 8 |

#### updated

- you have noted that your data frames are large and solution is giving you OOM
- logically aggregate first,  then merge will use less memory

```
pd.merge(
    df1.groupby(["myid","name"],as_index=False).agg(MAX_X=("x","max")),
    df2.groupby(["myid","name"],as_index=False).agg(MAX_Y=("y","max")),
    on=["myid","name"]
)
```

Comment: thanks @Rob. This is good for the OP examples, but I tried this with the full dataframes and received the error `Unable to allocate 123. GiB for an array with shape (34, 487520935) and data type int64`

Comment: not sure if it will help, you could try an inner or left join depending on your data. I choose outer (most expensive) as it won't drop data but is more expensive

Comment: have updated - reduce first, merge second

Comment: ha, just posted the same conclusion! I'll drop my answer and accept yours, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

you can try  `concat+groupby.max`

```
out = (pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).groupby(['myid','name']).max()
         .add_prefix("Max_").reset_index())
```

---

```
   myid name  Max_x  Max_y
0     1    A   15.0    9.0
1     2    B    3.0    6.0
2     3    C    3.0    6.0
3     4    D    4.0    2.0
4     5    E    8.0    8.0
```

Comment: thanks for start on this. the real dataframes have dozens of columns, so how do I specify which column I want the max for? and will also need to do it for minimum. sorry for leaving this out of the OP, I was trying to keep it simple

Comment: @a11 thats okay , can you edit your question with an example for your query. Check Robs answer as well. I mighht log out but if you dont get an answer will be back in the morning IST